# Typescript optional boolean or how to express true, false or undetermined

Tags: typescript

Let's assume, I'm writing a function like:

```
  const checkSomething = (data: Data): boolean | undefined => //whatever
```

it checks a property of the `data` that might be `true` or `false`, but also the `data` might not contain enough information to determine it.

In Java I'd express it like:

```
 Optional<Boolean> computeProperty(Data data)
```

Which is similar to `boolean | undefined` but my problem is that `undefined` is so called `falsy` value and it's very easy to misinterpret `undefined` as `false`

Is there any Typescript "standard" way of tackling it?

Or my best shot is to introduce an enum with values like `"true"`, `"false"`, `"undetermined"`?

Comment: (I'm not a downvoter) I don't think there is a "standard" way to do it, so you'll probably get a bunch of opinions here, unless you can [edit] the question to show how we can determine an objectively correct answer (i.e., what criteria do we judge answers against).  Personally my opinion is `boolean | undefined` is fine as long as you use `===` to test, but if you're worried, than a union of literals like `'T'|'F'|'?'` is also fine.  But I'm not going to post that as an answer because it's subjective and I don't have a source for it.

Comment: Relevant reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for explanation. I did not want to stir useless discussion. It seems there is no idiomatic way. Then that's the correct answer. Answer I kind expected, but with having background in different languages I just thought there must be a better option that I missed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in concept of optional type in TS. If you want just to express three states, you can use unions, as proposed by jcalz.

```js
function doWork(arg: any): 'T' | 'F' | '?';
```

If you want more of a 'optional' type so TS will yell at you if you try to access value without checking if it's there, then it can be done like this:

```js
type WithValue<T> = {
    value: T,
}

type Optional<T> = WithValue<T> | {};

// Handy helper function. You can also use if ('value' in opt) {} directly
const hasValue = <T,>(opt: Optional<T>): opt is WithValue<T> => {
    return 'value' in opt;
}

const func = (data: any): Optional<boolean> => {
    if (data.x) {
        return {
            value: true,
        }
    }
    return {};
}

const res = func('hello');

// @ts-expect-error TS will yell if you try to access value without check
res.value;

if (hasValue(res)) {
    console.log('Value is present', res.value);
} else {
    console.log('Optional is empty');
}
```

This works because right from `func` call TypeScript doesn't know if `res` is `{ value: T }` or just empty object. Thus if you try to access property on it without checking if it exists, TS will show error.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer with stress on sentence: 
There is no built-in concept of optional type in TS